# Clearing cache from browser

Tags: caching, apache-flex, browser

I have an application in Flex and that application generates files in PDF. To generate these files, I do an upload of a source file (Word format) where I can put some tags inside that file, for example #ds_version#, #cd_document#, etc.

The tags are replaced by database information and some tags has auto-increment, for example #ds_version#. Consequently the user can create many versions from that file in PDF

But the problem is: When the user going create a new version from source file, tags only receive the correct information when I clean the browser cache.

Does anyone know any way to clear browser cache by Flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the code in Web.config:

```
<caching>
  <profiles>
    <add extension=".swf" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
    <add extension=".odt" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
    <add extension=".doc" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />  
    <add extension=".docx" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's fix the problem, but I found another alternative using JavaScript: [Here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551)